# BigQuery unexpected _table_suffix result

Tags: google-bigquery

The following query:

```
select array_agg(distinct _table_suffix order by _table_suffix desc limit 10) from `project_id.visits.visit_20*`
```

returns:

[image]

but

```
select array_agg(distinct _table_suffix order by _table_suffix desc limit 10) from `project_id.visits.visit_202*`
```

returns:

[image]

How is it possible ? (The length of the first result should be 10).

Comment: I tried this with some tables that I created as well, and I have the same result even if I erase some numbers or put some more. This can be caused if you are using the cached result. You can disable the [cached results](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results#disabling_retrieval_of_cached_results) by clicking on the `more` tab, going to `query settings` and unmarking the checkbox of `Use cached results`. Additionally, cache lifetime in BigQuery is 24 hours, but the cached results are based on a best-effort query.

Comment: I disabled the cached results for the two queries but unfortunately i got the same lengths for the results (3 for the first result and 10 for the second result).

Comment: More precisely, i got today:
211123, 211122, 211121 for the first query and 
11123, ..., 11114 for the second query.

Comment: This is an unexpected behavior in BigQuery, you can create a case at the support team. to check if there is something in the streaming buffering of the job that causes this in your project.